# Why there is no pagetable_init in init_64.c of linux kernel

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, x86-64, page-tables

I am currently learning the kernel page table initialization process in Linux. As I am reading the codes, I found out that there is a function `pagetable_init()` in `init_32()` to initialize the kernel pagetable for 32-bit system. However, I found out there is no similar function in `init_64.c` for 64-bit system. So I am wondering how does the x86_64 in Linux initialize the kernel pagetable.

Answer (score 3):

For 80x86; you have to prepare page tables then switch to long mode (which must use your page tables), causing you to be in either "16-bit compatibility sub-mode of long mode" or "32-bit compatibility sub-mode of long mode"; and then after you're in long mode you can switch to 64 bit code.

Therefore, for `init_64.c` (because it's 64 bit code) something must have already initialized paging before the code is called.

For most cases (UEFI) the firmware initializes paging before starting the operating system's boot loader. Note that in this case paging is initialized by firmware as "everything identity mapped" - the kernel (or boot loader in theory) would still have to modify things to suit itself (e.g. map the kernel into kernel-space).

Comment: Can you give sone hints of where I can find the firmware that initializes the page table for the kernel?

Comment: @LubaA: Code to setup page tables (for firmware, to comply with UEFI specs which have nothing to do with Linux) is mostly all proprietary code (done by motherboard manufacturers, etc). There is at least one open source UEFI implementation you can see as an example (the TianoCore project) where you can find: https://github.com/tianocore/edk2/blob/8b76f235340922a6d293bff05978ba57d3b498e1/OvmfPkg/ResetVector/Ia32/PageTables64.asm